# How to display a property of an object nested in an array inside a template attribute?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I get the error:

> **TypeError: "someArr[0] is undefined"**.

When you try to access an object property inside a template:

```html
<th v-bind:data-id="someArr[0].id">{{someArr[0].name}}</th>
```

Despite the error, the data is displayed.

Source data for someArr:

```javascript
Array[0]: Object {id: "1", name: "One"}
Array[1]: Object {id: "2", name: "Two"}
```

Is it possible to get the value directly without using a loop?

**EDIT**

I call inside the block created() this method fetchData(), which via Ajax, retrieves data and populates the model. Now I will check your assumption, but why then the data is displayed?

Comment: Is the data populated initially or is it loaded subsequently? It sounds like `someArr` isn't available when you first render the component.

Comment: try something like `<th v-if="someArr[0]" v-bind:data-id="someArr[0].id">{{someArr[0].name}}</th>`

Comment: I call inside the block **created()**  this method **fetchData()**, which via Ajax, retrieves data and populates the model.
Now I will check your assumption, but why then the data is displayed?

Comment: Eureka! You are @boussadjra-brahim genius! Thank you, your solution worked.

Comment: You are right @skirtle, apparently the data did not have time to load.

Comment: If you're fetching it inside `created` then it won't be available during the first render. Once the data loads the component will render again, this time without an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow community !

When you use any value inside `vue data property`, Vue tracks it's value that's the whole purpose of the framework. Now the value connected to reactivity, and you binded that value to UI so whenever that value get changed Vue tracks it and re-render that module which is binded to the value and reflects the updated value.

In your case it's clear that there is a property Ex -

```
data() {
  return {
    someArr: []
  }
},
created() {
 // Await api call
 this.someArr = response
}
```

Now for the first render your value is `empty arr` which get updated once the async request get completed and that value get updated. But Obviously synchronous code will execute which throw the error that `someArr[0] is undefined` as value is empty.

For such case always preferred to check if the value exist.

```
<th v-if="someArr.length" v-bind:data-id="someArr[0].id">{{someArr[0].name}}</th>
```

Now `JS` engine will not execute or look for `someArr[0].id` if the array is empty, once you fetched the data updated it, Vue will re-render and this time it will look for id as array is having some value